# MySQL - do not select rows with the value "invalid"

Tags: mysql

I have a query which has this statement in the where clause:

```
 AND (s1_.sync_id IS NULL OR s1_.sync_id = 0)
```

In the database I have this value:

```
sync_id
NULL       --> NULL
invalid    --> String 'invalid'
```

The query does select the row with the string **"invalid"** as well. I do not see why, because it is neither **NULL** nor **0**.

I do want to select the rows with NULL or 0, but I do not want to select the row with a value which is different from these two.

Does anybody know what is happening here?

Thanks.

Comment: @Harshil I do want to select the rows with NULL or 0, but I do not want to select the row with a value which is different from these two.

Comment: `AND (s1_.sync_id IS NULL OR s1_.sync_id = '0')` coz sync_id should not be compared with integer value. or try this: `AND (s1_.sync_id <> 'invalid')`

Comment: I will go with s1_.sync_id = '0' - that works

Comment: Your data's dirty. Why not update all rows to have `NULL` instead of this "invalid" nonsense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small update required in your query:

```
AND (s1_.sync_id IS NULL OR s1_.sync_id = '0')
```

You need to cover `0` with `''` as `sync_id` stores strings not the Integers.